# Multiple images comparison with python

Tags: python, optimization

I'm an applied geophysics msc student and I would like your own opinions about my topic.
So... I have an initial model: [image]

and some predictive models. I was wondering if SSIM and MSE 
are enough to compare a number of predictive models with the initial and find the one that fits best.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not meant for this type of problems. You can try to post it in [data science stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The question is "are the predictive models better?". This is a complex question in geophysics.

Yes, of course MSE is a good start, but it will be biased against outliers, so you will have lots of small differences in your image.

SSIM will also be a compromise.

So the question is what do you think is a good predictive model. Then, based on this, you can decide the best cost function for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthiew for your quick response.